# I'm reading into a 256 byte string. I want to skip it, if it's all binary zeros (\x00) Is there a single test?

Tags: python, string, compare

Totally new to python.  Trying to parse a file but not all records contain data.  I want to skip the records that are all hex 00.

if record == ('\x00' * 256):   from a sample of print("-"*80))
gave a Syntax error, hey I said I was new.  :)

Thanks for the reply, I'm using 2.7 and reading like this....

```
with open(testfile, "rb") as f:
    counter = 0
    while True:
        record = f.read(256)
        counter += 1
```

Comment: Welcome ! Can you post an actual code snippet ? And maybe which Python version you are using.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show how you are reading each "record" of the binary file.

Comment: You are probably getting the syntax error because of an extra parenthesis symbol after the print statement. This code seems to work: `if a == '\x00' * 256: print '-' * 80`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example looks to be very close. I'm not sure about Python 2, but in Python 3 you should specify that a string is binary.
I would do something like:

```
empty = b'\x00' * 256
if record == empty:
    print('skipped this line')
```

Remember that Python 2 uses print statements, so you should do `print 'skipped this line'` instead.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed.

Comment: great. Please accept the answer to close the question then